# How to solve error while installing numba?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pycharm, numba

so I have a problem while I have try to install numba to python by using the pip command in CMD (pip install numba ), and I always get the following output and error :

```
Collecting numba
  Using cached numba-0.51.2.tar.gz (2.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in c:\users\se_320_gb\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from numba) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\se_320_gb\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from numba) (49.2.1)
Collecting llvmlite<0.35,>=0.34.0.dev0
  Using cached llvmlite-0.34.0.tar.gz (107 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for numba, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for llvmlite, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: llvmlite, numba
    Running setup.py install for llvmlite ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\se_320_gb\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Se_320_Gb\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_v76h2mu\\llvmlite_0c956b9ff442433e8d48ac4e37563a11\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Se_320_Gb\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_v76h2mu\\llvmlite_0c956b9ff442433e8d48ac4e37563a11\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Se_320_Gb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-phjgzn90\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\se_320_gb\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\llvmlite'
         cwd: C:\Users\Se_320_Gb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_v76h2mu\llvmlite_0c956b9ff442433e8d48ac4e37563a11\
    Complete output (27 lines):
    running install
    running build
    got version from file C:\Users\Se_320_Gb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_v76h2mu\llvmlite_0c956b9ff442433e8d48ac4e37563a11\llvmlite/_version.py {'version': '0.34.0', 'full': 'c5889c9e98c6b19d5d85ebdd982d64a03931f8e2'}
    running build_ext
    c:\users\se_320_gb\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe C:\Users\Se_320_Gb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_v76h2mu\llvmlite_0c956b9ff442433e8d48ac4e37563a11\ffi\build.py
    Trying generator 'Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Se_320_Gb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_v76h2mu\llvmlite_0c956b9ff442433e8d48ac4e37563a11\ffi\build.py", line 191, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\Se_320_Gb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_v76h2mu\llvmlite_0c956b9ff442433e8d48ac4e37563a11\ffi\build.py", line 179, in main
        main_win32()
      File "C:\Users\Se_320_Gb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_v76h2mu\llvmlite_0c956b9ff442433e8d48ac4e37563a11\ffi\build.py", line 88, in main_win32
        generator = find_win32_generator()
      File "C:\Users\Se_320_Gb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_v76h2mu\llvmlite_0c956b9ff442433e8d48ac4e37563a11\ffi\build.py", line 76, in find_win32_generator
        try_cmake(cmake_dir, build_dir, generator)
      File "C:\Users\Se_320_Gb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_v76h2mu\llvmlite_0c956b9ff442433e8d48ac4e37563a11\ffi\build.py", line 28, in try_cmake
        subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '-G', generator, cmake_dir])
      File "c:\users\se_320_gb\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 368, in check_call
        retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
      File "c:\users\se_320_gb\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 349, in call
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
      File "c:\users\se_320_gb\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "c:\users\se_320_gb\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
        hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    error: command 'c:\\users\\se_320_gb\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\se_320_gb\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Se_320_Gb\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_v76h2mu\\llvmlite_0c956b9ff442433e8d48ac4e37563a11\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Se_320_Gb\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_v76h2mu\\llvmlite_0c956b9ff442433e8d48ac4e37563a11\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Se_320_Gb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-phjgzn90\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\se_320_gb\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\llvmlite' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have tried to uninstall then reinstall PyCharm and python but these does not work
I think that the probleme have some thing with the environment variables
I am using a python version 3.9.1 with PyCharm version 2020.3.1 ,if any additional information needed ask me pls

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from your error that llvmlite was not installed correctly.

Looking at [this Github issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/6345), you're not the only person with this problem.

I think you might have to switch to an earlier version of Python.

Comment: Do think that I can manually reinstall llvmlite ? and How ?